# Standalone method in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@variants_hash = LineItem.find(:all, :joins => :drop_ship_orders, :conditions => {:drop_ship_order_line_items =>{:drop_ship_order_id  => params[:drop_ship_order_ids]}, :drop_ship_orders => {:completed_at.not_eq => nil, :retailer_id => current_user.retailer.id}}).group_by{ |li| li.variant }
@variants = @variants_hash.keys
```

And obviously it's not pretty, I was thinking of implementing it as a standalone method in my ActiveRecord.
I'll call the following instead: LineItem.find_variants(params, retailer_id)

How can I implement that standalone method and if there is a much easier and cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
def self.get_variants
   blah....
end
```